# iPhone - how to disable Shake for undoing read/unread email?

Tags: ios, email, undo-redo

Can anyone help me understand if there have been changes to the "shake-to-undo" feature specific to Mail using it to undo marking messages read/unread? My mom gets a pop-up just about every time she opens Mail, asking "Undo read message?"

We both have shake-to-undo enabled globally, but mine does not do this (nor do I want it to). Shake-to-undo typing is working equally for both of us.

In further troublehsooting, I notice that I'm still in iOS 12.3.1, and she's on 13.x (not at her phone rn).

Does anybody recall this behavior being specifically added in iOS 13? By any chance has it been changed since then? I've done a lot of searching on this, and there are countless posts from others who are frustrated by it.

We had to turn off the global setting to get her phone to stop doing this, which is unfortunately b/c it is otherwise an important and useful feature.

Comment: Don’t troubleshoot when you are feeling preoccupied or distracted  - https://daringfireball.net/2003/02/flowers_are_for_chumps

Answer (score -1):

- Open the settings app
- Swipe down slightly
- Enter **undo** in the search field
- Tap “Swipe to undo”
- Make your choice

[image: undo setting in the iOS settings app - accessability]

The setting is global and not app specific.

Since you didn’t list actual troubleshooting steps, once you conclude you can suppress this by disabling it globally and that it returns.

Look for other differences for your experience. Different accelerometer sensitivities, different actual accelerations or pursue software resets.

- power cycle it normally
- force reset the device
- Leave the undo off for a day globally
- restore the device
- swap or repair the hardware

Being organized is the only way to troubleshoot a frustrating situation like you mention.

Comment: I was very clear, I already know how to enable and disable "shake to undo." That is not the question. The question is why does one phone undo read messages, and the other does not, and can that be changed.

Comment: The setting is global, so I think I was clear as well @Avram. I’ll edit the answer to be more verbose and my comments less so.

Comment: Bmike, I fully understood your first message. It simply did not provide any new information. This is not a general question about the shake-to-undo feature. This question is about the Mail app behaving differently on one phone vs another.

Comment: I will update my question to make it more clear that I am asking for specific knowledge about changes in behavior of the shake-to-undo feature, not system-wide configuration or troubleshooting. I would appreciate it if you would delete your general responses as the intention of this question was to be specific, not repeat questions that are already covered here.

Comment: I disagree @Avram I feel this could help help others. If you downvoted, that’s excellent as I encourage everyone to answer and everyone to vote. My answer doesn’t have to be the one you use, or select  - yet still help others.